# REST Django - How to grab recently created Object

Tags: django, api, rest

I use a post method to create an instance of the class called Project.
When the Post method is done, I want to get the ID of the recently created Project-object. How would I do this?

my model looks like this:
models.py

```
class Project(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column = 'db_ID', primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500, default = None)
    descriptor = models.CharField(max_length = 1000, null = True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'projects'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and my view is this:
views.py:

```
class ProjectView(
    APIView,
):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ProjectSerializer(data = request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            user = request.user
            return Response({"status": "success", "data": serializer.data}, status = 200)
        else:
            return Response({"status": "error", "data": serializer.errors}, status = 400)
```

Comment: you should add `id` to `ProjectSerializer`'s fields. It'll automatically return created object's id in the response.

Answer (score 1):

`serializer.data`

will give you the recently created row in your model class and you can fetch data using ajax or any type script framework and you can find all data created based on your serializer class fields.

`serializer.errors`

will give you the errors that occurs in the saving process.

Try to implement this code for example using jQuery ajax:

```
success: function (data) {
                if (data.status === 'sucess') {
                    console.log(data.data)
                } else if (data.status === 'error') {
                    console.log(data.data)
                    
                }
            }
```